# Como imprimir o resultade de um SELECT (php / sql) em um lugar especifico na pagina HTML?

Tags: php, html, sql

Saudações,

Tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela de requisições de compra.
No meu html existe um painel onde será exibido o número de requisições de compra registrados.

Consegui fazer o SELECT direitinho e imprimir os resultados em uma pagina em branco.

Mas, o objetivo é imprimir o resultado dentro do painel de requisições que já existe em uma página HTML.

Como fazer isso?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
    <title>MPparts - seu mercado de peças</title>
  </head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.big-slide.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
    });
  </script>
<body>

<div id="interface">
    <section id="menulateral">

    <header id="cabecalhomenu">
        <figure class="foto-usuario" >
            <img src="_imagens/fotousuario.png">
            <figcaption>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </header>

    <nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="incluir_requisicao.php">Nova requisição</a></li>
            <li><a href="teste1.html">The Ballad of El Goodo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thirteen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">September Gurls</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </section>

    <section id="painelusuario">
        <header id="cabecalhopainel">
            <table id="tabelaindicadores" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="50px">
                <tr>
                    <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_requisicoes">Requisições<br>x </td>
                    <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_cotacoes">Cotações</td>
                    <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_transito">Em Transito </td>
                    <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_recebimento">Recebimento</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </header>

        <div id="areadetrabalho">

            <header id="cabecalhoareadetrabalho">

                teste


            </header>

            <IFRAME name= areadetrabalhoframe src="novarequisicao.html" frameBorder=0 width=100% height=100% scrolling=auto></IFRAME>


        </div>

    </section>




</div>
```

```
<?php
include ('conexao.php');

$listarequisicoes=mysqli_query($conexao,"select id_requisicao, 
count(id_requisicao) from tb_requisicoes group by id_requisicao having 
count(id_requisicao)>0 ") or die("erro");//lista todas as requisicoes cadastradas no banco de dados
$linhas= mysqli_num_rows($listarequisicoes);//conta requisicoes

if ($linhas==''){

    echo 'nenhum registro';
}
else{
    echo $linhas;
}
```

Comment: Entendi que você quer mostrar esse resultado na página em algum lugar especifico, mas onde é esse lugar? No `iframe`?

Outra coisa é a TAG utilizada na pergunta, você marcou como java, mas não vejo nada de java no seu código, não seria JavaScript?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. O lugar seria na TD q tem id= painel_requisicoes e o java foi errado msm.

Comment: Bem-vindo Rodrigo Maniezzo, caso alguma resposta resolva seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079 Caso queira fazer um tour pelo site acesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bem simples, você coloca a consulta ao banco de dados na página (Decidi colocar no `head`) e dentro da `td` que você quer mostrar as linhas, coloca o resultado (Esse resultado pode ser melhor formatado, coloquei como você postou), segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
    <title>MPparts - seu mercado de peças</title>

    <?php
        include ('conexao.php');

        $listarequisicoes=mysqli_query($conexao,"select id_requisicao, 
        count(id_requisicao) from tb_requisicoes group by id_requisicao having 
        count(id_requisicao)>0 ") or die("erro");//lista todas as requisicoes cadastradas no banco de dados
        $linhas= mysqli_num_rows($listarequisicoes);//conta requisicoes
    ?>

      </head>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.big-slide.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
        });
      </script>
    <body>

    <div id="interface">
        <section id="menulateral">

        <header id="cabecalhomenu">
            <figure class="foto-usuario" >
                <img src="_imagens/fotousuario.png">
                <figcaption>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </header>

        <nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="incluir_requisicao.php">Nova requisição</a></li>
                <li><a href="teste1.html">The Ballad of El Goodo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thirteen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">September Gurls</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </section>

        <section id="painelusuario">
            <header id="cabecalhopainel">
                <table id="tabelaindicadores" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="50px">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_requisicoes">
                            Requisições<br>
                            <?php
                                if ($linhas==''){
                                    echo 'nenhum registro';
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo $linhas;
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_cotacoes">Cotações</td>
                        <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_transito">Em Transito </td>
                        <td class="indicadorpainel" id="painel_recebimento">Recebimento</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </header>

            <div id="areadetrabalho">

                <header id="cabecalhoareadetrabalho">

                    teste


                </header>

                <IFRAME name= areadetrabalhoframe src="novarequisicao.html" frameBorder=0 width=100% height=100% scrolling=auto></IFRAME>

            </div>

        </section>

    </div>
```

Comment: Deu certinho, bastou fazer isso e salvar a pagina como php e não como html. Muito obrigado

Comment: Opa, esqueci de me atentar a extensão do arquivo hehe. Precisando, estamos ai.

Answer (score 0):

**No PHP**

```
if ($linhas==''){

    $texto = 'Requisições<br>nenhum registro';
}
else{

     $texto = 'Requisições<br>'.$linhas;
}
```

**HTML**

> Dentro do JavaScript inclua essa linha

```
$("#painel_requisicoes").html('<?php echo $texto ?>');
```